# Trying to use a movieclip on a mesh

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip, mesh

Im new here and I got a question, I need to use a movieclip on a mesh, I mean, make that the shape of my movieclip fits in a mesh, my movieclip now have a rectangular form, and I want it to adopt a cylindrical one.

Obviously, I want that my moviecliip keep all its funcionality, buttons, animations, etc.

Thx in advance.

Cyas.-

Comment: when you say form what Flash element do you mean? (Panel, Shape, etc...)

Comment: I think form = shape, not a flash element (?)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a few approaches to this:

1) the one I would go for, use a displacement map like this: http://dispatchevent.org/roger/cylinder-mapping/

2) use a 3d engine such as away3d, papervision or sandy and use your swf as a material on a cylindrical mesh

3) use pixel bender (not my first choice, but probably possible)

Comment: Gary, thx for the answer.

In my work I use away3d and I tryied that few days ago, and I find out that I couldnt keep the functionality nor the animation, only a frame of my movieclip like a bitmap...

I'll try the displacement aproach.

Thx.

(When I say form I mean shape, not a Flash element)